# Django AdminSite customization how to edit sites.py file? ("Properly")

Tags: python, django

My current goal is to show the number of registered Users on the admin interface, for example `<h1>Users Count: {{model.count}}</h1>` assuming model is already equal to the User model.

In order to achieve this, I have to add a single line in sites.py which is located in django.contrib.admin; is there any proper way to edit this file? Should I copy the entire django.contrib.admin?

Note: I edited the file in the venv and it works, but I want a cleaner way, where every modification is located under my admin app and not in the venv.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is your CustomAdminSite which is located in your local admin.py file. In this situation I had to add the following function **including** its required imports (Copied from django.contrib.admin.sites.py "in the AdminSite section"):

```
def _build_app_dict(self, request, label=None):
    """
            Build the app dictionary. The optional `label` parameter filters models
            of a specific app.
            """
    app_dict = {}

    if label:
        models = {
            m: m_a for m, m_a in self._registry.items()
            if m._meta.app_label == label
        }
    else:
        models = self._registry

    for model, model_admin in models.items():
        app_label = model._meta.app_label

        has_module_perms = model_admin.has_module_permission(request)
        if not has_module_perms:
            continue

        perms = model_admin.get_model_perms(request)

        # Check whether user has any perm for this module.
        # If so, add the module to the model_list.
        if True not in perms.values():
            continue

        info = (app_label, model._meta.model_name)
        model_dict = {
            'name': capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural),
            'object_name': model._meta.object_name,
            'perms': perms,
            'admin_url': None,
            'add_url': None,
            'count': model.objects.count(), {# !!----ONLY THIS LINE WAS ADDED------- #}
        }
        if perms.get('change') or perms.get('view'):
            model_dict['view_only'] = not perms.get('change')
            try:
                model_dict['admin_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % info, current_app=self.name)
            except NoReverseMatch:
                pass
        if perms.get('add'):
            try:
                model_dict['add_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_add' % info, current_app=self.name)
            except NoReverseMatch:
                pass

        if app_label in app_dict:
            app_dict[app_label]['models'].append(model_dict)
        else:
            app_dict[app_label] = {
                'name': apps.get_app_config(app_label).verbose_name,
                'app_label': app_label,
                'app_url': reverse(
                    'admin:app_list',
                    kwargs={'app_label': app_label},
                    current_app=self.name,
                ),
                'has_module_perms': has_module_perms,
                'models': [model_dict],
            }

    if label:
        return app_dict.get(label)
    return app_dict
```